# Building deb files for both Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb

While the tools are the same, the sections and distribution names are notably different between Ubuntu & Debian (and presumably other Debian-based distros).

For example, a Lua library's debian/control file for Debian might use

```
 Section: contrib/libdevel
```

while Ubuntu would use

```
 Section: universe/interpreters
```

What is the best way to make deb files for each when "universe" doesn't exist in Debian and "contrib" doesn't exist in Ubuntu given that the tools seem to all act upon a single source/config directory: debian? How does one reconcile this?

Note: this question also applies to changelog entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I need to do this, I create separate debian/* directories for each system I'm supporting. You could store them in lots of different ways: perhaps a dedicated source code repository called "packaging" that contains the directories for each system. You can then use a build or CI system (like Jenkins, Travis CI, or similar) to download your application's source code, download the packaging code for the system you are building the package for, and start the build process.

A tool you may want to take a look at to help make this easier is [pbuilder](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto) which makes it easy to build a package for many different versions of Debian or Ubuntu by making use of [chroots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

I also wrote a walk through of [how to use pbuilder](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/05/18/building-deb-packages-with-pbuilder/) that you may find helpful.